# Adobe Acrobat Reader doesn't want to open some links in PDF file

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have a PDF file that contains several links, among others to two Wikipedia articles. All links work except for the two Wikipedia links. After clicking on any link to an article on Wikipedia, Acrobat Reader displays the following message, and doesn't navigate to the page in a web browser:

> Adobe Acrobat does not allow connection to: en.wikipedia.org

[image]

After pressing the *Help* button, the page https://helpx.adobe.com/support/reader.html?mv=product is displayed which doesn't explain anything.

All links work if I open the PDF file in Google Chrome.

I have Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (32-bit) version 2021.001.20155.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wikipedia.org domain was blocked in the Trust Manager. I changed it by pressing this button: *Edit > Preferences > Trust Manager > Internet Access from PDF Files outside the web browser > Change Settings*, and now all links work.
It looks like I had accidentally blocked this domain.